# Bond Prices in terms of short and forward rates

Tags: interest-rates

Of course, a pure discount bond price $P(t,T)$ may be stated in terms of its yield $R(t,T)$ as
$$
P(t,T) = e^{-R(t,T)(T-t)}.
$$
Let's assume both the (instantaneous) short rate $r(t)$ and (instantaneous) forward rate $f(t,T)$ are deterministic functions.  The relationships to discount bond prices are
\begin{align}
r(t) & = -\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \log P(t,t), \\
f(t,T) & = -\frac{\partial}{\partial T} \log P(t,T).
\end{align}
From this, it is clear that
$$
P(t,T) = \exp\left(-\int_t^T f(t,u) \, du\right) \qquad (1).
$$

On the other hand, the bond price is often stated in terms of risk-neutral expectations *using the short rate*, such as
$$
P(t,T) = E_Q\left(\exp\left(-\int_t^T r(u) \, du\right) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right),
$$
and since I am assuming $r(t)$ is deterministic, it should be that
$$
P(t,T) = \exp\left(-\int_t^T r(u) \, du\right) \qquad (2).
$$
Comparing Eqns (1) and (2), it seems like
$$
\int_t^T r(u) \, du = \int_t^T f(t,u) \, du.
$$

Does this even make sense?  Furthermore, since $P(t,T) = e^{-R(t,T)(T,t)}$, we would get
$$
R(t,T) = \frac{1}{T-t}\int_t^T f(t,u) \, du = \frac{1}{T-t}\int_t^T r(u) \, du.
$$
That is, the yield is both the average of the instantaneous forward rate (this is true), *and* the average of the instantaneous spot rate.  Is this latter statement true?

Answer (score 1):

Since the interest rate is deterministic, for $t< u \le T$,
\begin{align*}
f(t, u) &= -\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \ln P(t, u)\\
&=-\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \ln \left(E\left(\exp\left(-\int_t^u r(s)\, ds \right) \mid \mathcal{F}_t\right) \right)\\
&=-\frac{\partial}{\partial u} \ln \left(\exp\left(-\int_t^u r(s)\, ds\right)  \right)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\int_t^u r(s)\, ds \\
&= r(u).
\end{align*}
Consequently, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{T-t}\int_t^T f(t, u)\, du = \frac{1}{T-t}\int_t^T r(u)\, du.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

This says that if rates are deterministic, the spot rate follows the forward rates that are initially observed.  Makes sense.